# How to adjectivize "commence"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, spelling

I was uncertain if the adjective of *commence* was *commenceable* or *commencable* (meaning *being able or allowed to begin* or *being eligible to start*).

According to my googlificational skills, neither is. So, I wonder how to spell it? Or doesn't such a form exists in English at all?

Comment: Interesting http://www.dictionary.com/browse/commence shows 'commenceable, adjective' as a related form but no definitions of commenceable turn up anywhere. I don't think this should be closed as general reference, because it's not as straight-forward as it seems.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree with you that it shouldn't be closed as general reference. However, I'm not certain why you point that out, since there's been no "helpful", premature nags about it being that. Or do I miss something?

Comment: It came up in the review queue and I thought I saw 'answerable by a dictionary' as one of the reasons that someone gave for wanting to close it. I try to explain in a comment why I vote to leave a question open so other reviewers can see my reasoning, and they might think a little harder before they go along with the other votes.

Comment: I appreciate that. It's very thorough of you, I must admit. Sadly, there are a few trigger-happy users around. Luckily, the system works (I see 2 closing votes but no more). I'm very satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not *commencable*, the *c* in that situation is soft only if *e* or *i* follow (e.g. *invincible* but *communicable*) and adding "-able" or "-ible" to the end of a word doesn't change it's pronunciation.

In case you wonder further about the logic in choosing "-able" or "-ible", the heuristic from [here](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/when-use-able-and-ible) is pretty helpful:

> When the root word looks like a whole word then you should be able to add *-able*.
>
> When the full root word is not a whole word you can add *-ible*.

There is *defensible* (*defenseable* is definitely a no-no) which doesn't follow the above and probably a couple more exceptions.

So, *commenceable*.  Not *commencible* or *commencable*.